# Qt Creator 2.1.0 can't find Qt, looks in wrong place

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I've recently installed 4.7.1 (and 4.7.2, same results) alongside QtCreator 2.1.0.  When I try to compile the default (empty) QtGui application, I get 'QtGui/QApplication: No such file or directory' errors.  If I and the file location to INCLUDEPATH in the .pro file, I get 'can't find -lQtGui'; if I add the library to LIBS, the program compiles and runs.

But modifying the .pro file like this really isn't a viable solution, it's very difficult for large programs for one thing, and in any case I can't believe this is what the developers intend.  I've used various versions of Qt for several years now and have not had this problem.

According to the Makefile, Qt is looking for these files/libs in directories that don't exist, specifically ~/include and ~/lib ('/home/matt' is my home directory, on Ubuntu):

> INCPATH       = -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.2/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/home/matt/include/QtCore -I/home/matt/include/QtGui -I/home/matt/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I.moc/release-shared -I.uic/release-shared
>
> LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS)  -L/home/matt/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lQtGui -lQtCore

Why is it trying to look in these folders?  I've tried changing the HOME and even PWD system environment variables, it didn't change anything.  NB Qt and QtCreator are both installed in my home directory.  Does anybody know what the issue is here?

Matt

P.S. I've had this on QtCentre for awhile but haven't heard anything there.

P.P.S I've gone ahead and filed a bug report, http://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-18230

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-18230

Turns out .qmake.cache was out of date, deleting it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The LIBS variable in the Makefile must point to the directory from the QtCreator library directory as follows :

```
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS) ~/QtSDK/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread
```

Then run : `make`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that Qt Creator hasn't detected where you installed the 4.7.x toolkits. Look in Tools->Options->Qt4 (on a Mac Preferences->Qt4) and add toolkit versions (the "+" button). What you need to identify are paths to qmake for whatever version you want to build.

Comment: I've tried both /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.2/bin and ~/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.2 as the qmake locations, and it doesn't make a difference (qmake does in fact exist in both places).  The make command that is generated invokes the same nonexistent directories.  Is there something else I should try to set?